# In Jquery Chosen plugin remove selection if user selects a particular value

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-chosen

I have the following multi select and I am using [Jquery Chosen](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/) plugin

```
  <select multiple="multiple" class="chzn-select span3" name="requestCategory"   id="requestCategory">
        <option selected="selected" value="">All</option>
        <option value="2">Electrical</option>
       <option value="4">Emails</option>
       <option value="3">Filming Permits</option>
       <option value="10">test1</option>
    </select>
```

Client wants to make sure that i do not allow user to select ALL if any other value is selected or if user selects any other value then automatically deselect/remove ALL; because ALL = all categories so having individual option does not make sense. How do i do this?

Answer (score 0):

Check if more than one item is selected, or if only one item is selected that it is not the first one - in these cases disable All.

```
$('.chzn-select').on('change', function() {
    var selectedOpts = $('option:selected', this);

    if(selectedOpts.length > 1 || selectedOpts.first().index() !== 0) {
        $('option', this).first().attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zCk2z/5/

Answer (score 0):

at first change of option [simple] removes the All category.
but i recomand to disable the item, it looks better use `.attr('disabled', 'disabled')` instead of  `.remove();`

```
$('#requestCategory').change(
function(){
$(this).find('option:contains("All")').remove()
})
```